# Angular: Call directive controller function from separate controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have an app called myApp. There is a directive for a menu component. This directive has a controller defined on it. Now, from another controller that loads the view, I want to call methods of that menu directive's controller.

What does the code look like to do that? How can the other controller call methods on the menu directive's controller?

Comment: This wreaks of code smell. If the two controllers are correctly designed, they shouldn't need to call each other. They should monitor and react to changes to the model. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Being a menu directive, it's more likely Chris wants to react to a user action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trying to go `controller -> directive` when you should be binding a function to some delegating call that goes `controller <- directive`.

For an example of this, you can check out [angular-ui/bootstrap's tabs directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/ab0387c041a2e295cb32b161cd66e52d78de0690/src/tabs/tabs.js#L187) onSelect and onDeselect:

```
.directive('tab', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    require: '^tabset',
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'template/tabs/tab.html',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      active: '=?',
      heading: '@',
      onSelect: '&select', //This callback is called in contentHeadingTransclude
                          //once it inserts the tab's content into the dom
      onDeselect: '&deselect'
    },
    // etc.
```

Using the `&` expression allows you to bind to a function as a callback.

An example of this usage would be a scope-bound function in your target controller:

```
$scope.selectedTab = function(){ alert('woohoo'); };
```

Which is 'bound' to the directive's function in the view:

```
<tab select="selectedTab()">
```

The tabs directive also has a good example of how to communicate between two different directives controllers. [See tabset controller's ctrl.select](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/ab0387c041a2e295cb32b161cd66e52d78de0690/src/tabs/tabs.js#L16-L25). A `tab` directive requires a parent `tabSet` controller with the require:

```
.directive('tab', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    require: '^tabset',
```

The `tab` directive can access the `tabset` controller's select function in the compile function:

```
compile: function(elm, attrs, transclude) {
  return function postLink(scope, elm, attrs, tabsetCtrl) {
    scope.$watch('active', function(active) {
      if (active) {
        tabsetCtrl.select(scope);
      }
    });

    scope.disabled = false;
    if ( attrs.disabled ) {
      scope.$parent.$watch($parse(attrs.disabled), function(value) {
        scope.disabled = !! value;
      });
    }

    scope.select = function() {
      if ( !scope.disabled ) {
        scope.active = true;
      }
    };

    tabsetCtrl.addTab(scope);
    scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      tabsetCtrl.removeTab(scope);
    });

    //We need to transclude later, once the content container is ready.
    //when this link happens, we're inside a tab heading.
    scope.$transcludeFn = transclude;
  };
}
```

So there you have how to execute code from some non-directive controller as a result of some action happening in your directive and how to execute some inter-directive functions as a result of directive `require` constraints.

edit: For anyone interested, here's the documentation for a directive's expressions: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api